# Cocoa app with ITK, VTK to read DICOM file

Tags: xcode, dicom, itk

I have xcode 3.2.6 and Mac OS X 10.6.8, so I've downloaded ITK 3-2.20 and VTK, Cmake 2.8-5.

I have installed ITK and VTK using Cmake, then I created Xcode projects ITK and VTK also using Cmake. I set target "ALL_BUILD" and after this run target "install". So I can run some tests from VTK and they work!

But could anyone say what I should do to create Xcode project (Cocoa app) for reading and displaying DICOM files using ITK and VTK libraries???

I can't understand how to use for example DicomImageReadWrite.cxx for creating Cocoa aplication.

Does anybody have an example of similar Xcode projects? (I have osirix.xcodeproj but when I try to run it a lot of mistakes appear)

Comment: I tried to use SimpleCocoaVTK but there is no file .cxx in the folder SimpleCocoaVTK and this project does not work - 1 error appears "_fopen$UNIX2003", referenced from: [a lot of files ] ld: symbol(s) not found... I changed SDK from 10.4 to 10.6 and nothing helps, so I don't know for what reason, maybe there is a conflict between VTK, ITK, Xcode and Mac OS..


I have an experience of using MATLAB - it is very simple to read, write and show DICOM images:

dicomread('/Users/.../5.dcm');

just one line and you have a matrix of this image.

Comment: Also I tried to use python in Xcode, I found xcodeproject, which can read and show DICOM image, but if I want to add a very simple textfields to evaluate average of digits like this http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/pyobjc.html 

Example from apple.com does not work in this app...

And I wonder how it was simple to work with .dcm in Matlab in comparison with Xcode. 

But Matlab has a bad 3D visualization for .dcm and not so rich tools to build a nice GUI, that's why I decide to try Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to investigate Qt instead of Cocoa for visualization.  The Slicer project has been moving to that platform, and it has been very successful in ITK/VTK/Qt graphical integration.

http://www.slicer.org/slicerWiki/index.php/Slicer4:Developers

The Slicer (i.e. National Alliance of Medical Image Computing) is also a very receptive and open community to helping create great software.

The Qt platform also provides cross platform compatibility.